# How to read specific lines in a file and insert them to a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, file, sorting, dictionary

I have a text file with format :

```
    2014-04-10
    Arjun 22  Class 10   60
    Anil  23  Class 09   85
    2013-03-10
    Jhon  21  Class 10   78
```

How should the code be, if I want the dictionary as shown :

```
  {'2014_Arjun' : ['22','Class 10','60'],'2014_Anil':['23','Class 09','85'],'2013_Jhon':['21','Class10','78']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to iterate over file lines, try parsing the line into the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) via [strptime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) - if successful, remember the year of the date, if not - parse the line via [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and write to the `data` dict:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re


data = {}
pattern = re.compile('(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+\s\d+)\s+(\d+)')
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            year = datetime.strptime(line.strip(), '%Y-%m-%d').year
        except ValueError:
            item = pattern.match(line.strip()).groups()
            data[str(year) + "_" + item[0]] = item[1:]

print data
```

prints:

```
{'2013_Jhon': ('21', 'Class 10', '78'), 
 '2014_Arjun': ('22', 'Class 10', '60'), 
 '2014_Anil': ('23', 'Class 09', '85')}
```

Make sure you understand what is going on here. If not - feel free to ask in comments.

Comment: Thanks..I understood the code! Small query, how can I insert the same values to dictionary, but if the date formart is not mentioned, only some string "Class Data - 1" or Class Data -2! please help me!

Comment: @user3347570 cannot say without a sample input. Probably, better ask in a separate thread/question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This one is the simplest solution I can imagine, if you really use TSV file format (Tab Separated Values):

```
PATH = r"C:\text.txt"
reader = open(PATH, 'rb')
result = {}
for line in reader:
    if line.count("\t") == 0:
        year = line.split("-")[0]
    else:
        name, day, class_no, mark = line.split(TAB)
        key = year + "_" + name
        value = [day, class_no, mark]
        result[key] = value
reader.close()
```

The "result" dictionary is what you asked for :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write this for you but it should help put you on a path.

If the format of your file is going to consistently be

```
YYYY-MM-DD
Name ## Class ## ##
```

Then the following is fairly simple.

You can do the following, check the line to see if it contains 'Class'.
If it doesn't (which implies that the line contains YYYY-MM-DD), then you now have a dictionary key prefix and can split on '-' to pull the year.
If it contains class, then you can now complete your dictionary prefix (YYYY_Name) and assign the remaining values in a list with d["YYYY_Name"] as the key.